# TensorFlow - SavedModelBuilder

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, save, builder

I have a TF model which I want to save at various increments.  The code I am using to do this is below.  Every 100 steps I want to create a new model, so I am calling `builder.save()` then.

Question:  do I need to call the whole of block 2 every time I want to save or do I just need to call `builder.save()`?

```
#  For exporting the model in SavedModel format
export_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(out_dir, "Model_Exports"))
builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)
#  Create classification signature - describes what model is being exported
tensor_info_x = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(cnn.input_x)
tensor_info_y = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(cnn.input_y)

classification_signature = (
  tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
    inputs={'documents': tensor_info_x},
    outputs={'scores': tensor_info_y},
    method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.CLASSIFY_METHOD_NAME)
)

#  BLOCK2 - Adding metagraph and variables to export  
builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
  sess,
  [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
  signature_def_map={
    'classify':
      classification_signature,
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`SavedModelBuilder`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/builder/SavedModelBuilder) is a simple assembler of the protobuf file. The `save` method only flushes the current structure in memory to the file on disk.

If you create a `builder` and call `builder.save()` without adding meta graph and variables, the call will succeed, but the saved [`SavedModel`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/protobuf/saved_model.proto) protobuf is going to be empty (except for the schema version, so the total file size will be 2 bytes). There is no practical use in this. Likewise it doesn't make a lot of sense to call `save` multiple times without adding anything new to it.

See also the description in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/builder/SavedModelBuilder):

> To build a `SavedModel`, the first meta graph must be saved with variables. Subsequent meta graphs will simply be saved with their graph definitions.